# dropdown navigation menu

Tags: navigation

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages <span><img src="<?php /*echo get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/img/icons/caret.svg' );*/ ?>" alt=""></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#feedback">Feedback</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#pricing">Compare</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

how can I add those classes present in li tag using the wp_nav_menu() function?

```
<?php 
        $defaults = array(
          'container' => false,
          'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
          'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
        );
        wp_nav_menu($defaults);
      ?>
```

Comment: You can't, you need a custom walker. If you're using Bootstrap one already exists that you can use: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: appreciated your help but It's still not working. The whole dropdown list is displaying.

Comment: By default wordpress provides dropdown menus, you can use scripts and style to adjust that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved guys thanks to  Rajilesh Panoli,
from github link provided in the above comment. 
download wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php and copy that file to your root directory of the theme and include that file in your functions.php file, then
use following code:

```
'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
          'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
```

in the wp_nav_menu() function in the header.php file (or wherever you have used this function).